# Rails including different levels of nested has_many relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So, I've got three ActiveRecord models. On User is 2 has_many relationships, one for `:accounts` and one for `:authorizations` which is an alias for a collection of transactions. Account has a collection of `:transactions`.

1. User
2. Account
3. Transaction

So far, I have been able to include User, its `:accounts` and its `:transactions` using:

`@user.to_json(:include => {:accounts => {:include => :transactions}})`

> I want to include the collection of transactions called
>   `:authorizations` that User has as well. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

```
@user.to_json(:include => [{:accounts => {:include => :transactions}}, :authorizations])
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried using that but I got this error: "#<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column transactions.user_id does not exist\nLINE 1: SELECT \"transactions\".* FROM \"transactions\" WHERE \"transacti...\n                                                          ^\n: SELECT \"transactions\".* FROM \"transactions\" WHERE \"transactions\".\"user_id\" = $1>"

Comment: Do you get the same error message if you do @user.to_json(:includes => :authorizations)? If so, then the relation isn't set up properly.